# Using RIGHT JOIN to match page data to the page

Tags: php, mysql

In my code, I am trying to join page names and page data names so that I am able to populate a web page with the data in my databases. The two tables look like the following pictures.

**page_data**

[image: Table 1]

**pages**

[image: Table 2]

So when I ran the following code in my PHP function I did not expect the echo to output `1`.

```
function merge_page($dbc) {
    $q = "SELECT pages.page_name, page_data.section_name 
         FROM page_data 
         RIGHT JOIN 'page_data' 
         ON pages.id = page_data.section_page_id";

    $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
    echo print_r($r);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected something along the lines of

```
pages.page_name    page_data.section_name 
   Welcome               Section 1
   Welcome               Section 2
   Welcome               Section 3
   Welcome               Section 4
   Welcome               Section 5
```

I would appreciate any help in fixing this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use an inner join (between page_data and pages ) *and not a right join between page_data  and page_data*

```
"SELECT pages.page_name, page_data.section_name 
 FROM page_data 
 INNER  JOIN 'pages' 
     ON pages.id = page_data.section_page_id";
```

or left join if the rows could don't match

```
"SELECT pages.page_name, page_data.section_name 
 FROM page_data 
 LEFT  JOIN 'pages' 
     ON pages.id = page_data.section_page_id";
```

Answer (score 1):

Using print_r directly on mysqli result is wrong.

```
function merge_page($dbc) {
$q = "SELECT pages.page_name, page_data.section_name 
     FROM page_data 
     RIGHT JOIN 'page_data' 
     ON pages.id = page_data.section_page_id";

$r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);
$result = array();
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $result[] = $row;
    }
}
return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this maybe? 
`echo print_r($r->mysqli_fetch_array)`

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or
>   EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For
>   other successful queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.
>   [- docs](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)

Edit: oh, I see the problem**s**. The is no "pages" table, and `'` is making the second reference to `page_data` into a string (which you can't JOIN to obviously).

Comment: Unfortunately, this causes an error as `$r` is a `non-object`. This is why I believe the problem lies with the query and not the result. However thank you for the answer

Comment: @Dan see edit. Also in my experience, most devs stay away from `RIGHT` join and rewrite as/think in terms of `LEFT` join. In complicated queries, RIGHT JOIN makes reading queries cumbersome (especially if mixed with other joins).

Comment: Also, when in doubt, run your query in a query browser of some sort (PHPMyAdmin, MySQL Workbench, SqlYog, etc....) and see what errors it spits at you.

Comment: Okay. Thank you for the edit but I do not understand what you mean by the `pages` table doesn't exist. And how would you suggest I fix my problem? Also, I am running my query in my browser and it isn't returning any errors. This is why I am confused to as why I cannot get the desired results

Comment: @Dan the query you've shown does not have `pages` as a table. It has `...FROM page_data RIGHT JOIN 'page_data'...`